# How is a rendering platform different from a web browser

Tags: networking, web, browser, rendering, client-side

What exactly is a rendering platform, is it different from a web browser or part of it or a layer beneath the browser?

As far as I understand a rendering platform is the one which actually parses the content and displays it on the screen, am i right? If so, what does a browser do? Does it just provide the interface which has menu bar etc. and developer tools? Also what are some examples of good rendering platform?

Can someone please explain in a simple way?

Answer (score 1):

Exactly.  The renderer (more commonly called a rendering **engine**) takes HTML/CSS/JavaScript and displays it in a view.  A web browser takes that view, sticks it in a window, adds pull-down menus, contextual menus, history, download tracking, and all the other functionality beyond what actually happens in the browser window.